# How can I add EC2 instances for different ECS clusters?

Tags: amazon-ecs

I want to setup 2 ECS clusters: TEST and PROD.
To allow EC2 instances to become part of your cluster, you need to have the ECS-agent running together with an ECS-Role. How can I make sure that DEV and PROD run on separated servers (instances)?

Answer (score 1):

Paste the following code in your EC2 User-data section:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=your_cluster_name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html